# How to use PHP to access MySQL shell?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, shell, command-line

Currently I have a shell script within my application that depending on what argument you pass it, it will log you into either the live or development MySQL database shell. It works fine, no problem there.

The issue/challenge I am having is that if in the case my MySQL credentials (host / port) change for either the live or development database then I will manually have to edit this shell script, updating it will the new arguments. Problem is, I have done this before but I never want to have to do it again.

What I would like to do is have a PHP script (mysql.sh.php) that when executed, depending on the argument passed to it will log you into either the live or development database shell. How it will differ from the shell script is that it will pull the current credentials (and even host and port) from a PHP configuration class and pass those as arguments to a shell command that will log into the respective database.

Below gives you an illustration of what I am attempting.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
 <?php
    include ('common.php');
    //Pull info from PHP class right here

    exec("mysql --host={$myhostnotyours} --user={$myusernotyours} -p{$mypassnotyours} {$thedatabase}");
```

What I expect or would like is

```
mysl>
```

However, the command just hangs and I am not presented with the MySQL shell.

I would like to know if there is a way to accomplish what I am trying.

Thanks!

Comment: you're doing this via browser, or on the command line? it's impossible to do it via browser without heroic measures/plugins - http is not a protocol for this kind of thing.

Comment: I'm using command line.

Comment: Couldn't you use proc_open and manually write php's stdin to the mysql input stream? (If I'm not missing what you try to it may work, it's still a hack though)

Comment: OK. Never heard of this function but it seems like a viable solution as I am writing a test script that is working for the most part. However, I think there is a fundamental similarity between this new approach and the approach that I posted originally that is causing it not to work because I am getting the same effect / response which is that the program is hanging, it is not getting the data written to the stdout pipe, at least not unless I close the stdin pipe before (which I can't / shouldn't because I would need the program to be interactive).